# new line character is not working properly while writing from excel to text file

Tags: python, excel, io, xlrd

I want to read from excel and write the content into a text file. The following source code does my job except one thing. The content of a sample text file i read from excel and write into text file looks like this:

```
test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4\ntest5
```

However i want it to be as following :

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

I try to write the file with wb mode but it does not work.

Here is my code. What should i do?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
import xlrd

def omer():

    #excel file is opened.
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('codes_autoscript_table_export.xls')

    #sheet names of the excel file is returned.
    sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
    #print (sheet_names)
    #print (sheet_names[0])

    #first sheet of the excel can be chosen in two ways :
    # xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])  #first way
    xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)                # second way
    #print (xl_sheet.name)

    #any row of the chosen sheet can be read.
    #print (xl_sheet.row(0)) # returns [text:'AUTOSCRIPT', text:'SOURCE', text:' ']
    #print (xl_sheet.row(1))    # returns [text:'VFOWNER', text:'(CLOB) mbo.setValueNull("OWNERGROUP")', text:' ']

    row = xl_sheet.row(1)
    filename = str(row[0])[6:-1] + ".py"
    filecontent = str(row[1])[13:-1]
    print  (filename)
    print  (filecontent)

    print ("# of columns : " + str(xl_sheet.ncols))   # Number of columns
    print ("# of rows : " + str(xl_sheet.nrows))   # Number of columns

    for i in range(1, xl_sheet.nrows):    # Iterate through rows
        oneRow = xl_sheet.row(i)
        filename = str(oneRow[0])[6:-1]  + ".txt"
        filecontent = str(oneRow[1])[13:-1]
        #print  (filename)
        my_file = open('./output/' + filename ,'w')
        my_file.write(filecontent)
        my_file.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    omer()
```

Answer (score 0):

To append a new line after writing change writeline to

```
my_file.write(filecontent + '\n')
```

if the content is already a string then you use `writelines` to write all the lines back

```
content = 'test1\ntest2\ntest3\ntest4\ntest5' #generates a list removing the new line

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(content)
```

if this dosen't work try this

```
content = content.split() # returns ['test1', 'test2'....]
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in content:
        f.write(i + '\n')
```

Comment: filecontent is a string and contains already \n characters. But it is not working

Comment: i''ve edited my answer. it should work now there is no need to split the strings `writelines` would write to the file and when it encounters `\n` it would move to a new line

Comment: you directly assign a string to content, and thus it s working properly. However, in my case, i read from excel to this content, thus it does not work! You should make your tests by reading from excel file as in my example.

Comment: you should post a snapshot of your excel file so i can see exactly how the structure is. i've edited my answer though, also content should be a `str` only strings can be written when a file is open in this mode.if it isn't convert it using `str(content)`